# What is the Singular Value Decomposition for the Zero Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I am interested in the singular value decomposition of a matrix: $\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{U} \mathbf{S} \mathbf{V}^T$.

Suppose $\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{0}$ (zero matrix) and square.  Clearly, $\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{0}$, but what about $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}^T$ -- Do they have defined values?

When use MATLAB, $\mathbf{U} = \mathbf{V} = \mathbf{I}$, but is this a definition or pure luck?  If so, why is it defined as such, since any matrix for $\mathbf{U}$ or $\mathbf{V}$ will satisfy the decomposition - it does not even need to be orthogonal.  Is there some sort of proof that it must indeed fall to a specific value?

```
>> [U, S, V] = svd(zeros(3))

U =

     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1


S =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0


V =

     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1
```

Comment: http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/d1/teaching/ss10/MFI2/kap47.pdf

Comment: For any square matrix $M$, you're guaranteed to find a diagonal matrix $S$ with non-negative diagonal entries and orthogonal matrices $U$ and $V$ such that $M = USV^T$, however, $S$ is only unique up to permutation of the diagonal entries, whilst for any fixed choice of $S$, $U$ and $V$ aren't unique at all. In the case of $M = 0$, you're forced to take $S = 0$, in which case *any* orthogonal $U$ and $V$ do the job, since $U0V^T = 0$. What MATLAB does is apply an algorithm to numerically compute a *particular* choice of $S$, $U$ and $V$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A matrix has not necessarily only one decomposition in singular value, so $U$, $V$, and $S$ aren't well defined, Matlab give you one of the solutions...

For example, if $(U,S,V)$ is a solution, $(-U, S, -V)$ is one too.